# Choose which database connection to run

Tags: php, database, if-statement, pdo

so i'm having my database connection in my project. The file has a local and an online request, one is commented out when i work on localhost.

is there a way in php for it to look up which one it has to use?

like if url = localhost/blabla use local else use online?

Here is the connection.

```
try{
    //local connection
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host = 127.0.0.1; dbname=XXXX', 'root','');

    //local online
    //$db = new PDO('mysql:host = XXXXX; dbname=XXXXX', 'xxxxx','*****');

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$db->exec("set names utf8");

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Hope somone can help if it's possible, thanks

Comment: One way to go would be to define your credentials based on URL (or whatever). This way you won't have to worry about multiple connections in your code. `If(url == 'x' ) { $username='foo'; { else } $username = 'bar' }`

Comment: If your local db connection string is different than production then I suggest having a config file that sets it and you would just make sure those are set appropriately in each environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do this, put your `db.php` in it's own folder, after uploading it to the server, then change the user rights so you can't overwrite it with your local connection

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't check for the URL but setup a `config file`. Then you set `DEVELOPMENT` on `0` on the server, and on `1` if you are local.

config.php

```
<?php
    define('DEVELOPMENT', 1);
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
    if(DEVELOPMENT) {
        // setup your local DB
    } else {
        // setup your live db
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it did the job, i knew it was possible in some how.

Comment: @user3426191 If it was helpful to you then accept this answer so other people can utilize this thread :) ( the check symbol)

Comment: i have to wait 3 minutes before i can accept it, but i will

Answer (score 0):

You can know the IP through the `$_SERVER` variable,so:

```
define('LOCALHOST', 'XX.XX.XX.XX');

if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == LOCALHOST)
{
  //open connection to the localhost users db
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host = 127.0.0.1; dbname=XXXX', 'root','');
}else{
  //open connection to rest of users db
  $db = new PDO('whatever', 'root','');
}
```